# How to copy the artifacts from slave to Jenkins workspace?

Tags: jenkins

I'm running a jenkins job on a slave and i want to store the generated artifacts in the server.Since the job is currently running on the slave the artifacts are also created there.

I tried using post build actions --->archive the artifacts.But it throws the following build error

```
ERROR: No artifacts found that match the file pattern "**/*.gz". Configuration error?

ERROR: '**/*.gz' doesn't match anything: '**' exists but not '**/*.gz'
```

Any help in this regards is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like [Copy To Slave Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+To+Slave+Plugin) is what you need

It can copy to slave (before build) and from slave (after build)

> Copy files back to master node:
>   To activate this plugin for a given job, simply check the Copy files back to the job's workspace on the master node checkbox in the Post-build Actions section of the job. You then get the same two fields as for the Copy files to slave node before building section (note that label in the screenshot is old):

Comment: On the linked page it says: "Distribution of this plugin has been suspended due to unresolved security vulnerabilities"

Comment: @CaptainWhippet Did you find a better solution for this requirement?

Comment: @UmutCatal my apologies, this is from a couple of years ago and I can't remember exactly what I did. But I think the copy to slave plugin eventually worked.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to copy artifacts from JobA to the workspace of some other Job, you can do it using the [Copy Artifact Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) which is very simple to understand.

In case you just want to archive the artifacts already in JobA, then you are already in this direction and need to check what you are missing... are you sure that the artifacts are in the current workspace?

Doron

Comment: Hi Doron, I would want to know if by current workspace you mean the Jenkin server workspace or the slave where the job is being built. Because as the .gz file is the artifact that is created in the slave server.but when i use the Archive the artifact option it says there are no such files.